# Hydrogen atom nodes and Bohmian trajectories

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-interpretations, orbitals, bohmian-mechanics

Wouldn't the fact that the solutions to the hydrogen atom orbital shape have nodes prove that the Bohmian interpretation is incorrect, since in that interpretation, the electrons would have a fixed trajectory, and that would mean we can sample it being in one of those nodes, while passing from one probability 'blob' to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The nodes are located where there is no probability density so you don't see the particle there. You don't see it in the lab, and you don't see it in Bohmian Mechanics.

It is a mystery why you would think they are there. I'm sure you've read the Bohmian mechanics makes the same predictions. And you know the equation for the how the particle moves and it doesn't move into a node.

So why would you say it does when you know it doesn't? You don't need a particle to move. Keep in mind that where you think there might be kinetic energy there can be quantum potential energy instead. And keep in mind that if your wave is all real, for instance, then there is no motion of the particle so the quantum potential in that state has an equal and opposite gradient as the classical potential at every point. This is fine.

> Wouldn't the particle move between the anti-nodes? And when it does so, wouldn't it have a chance of being found in the nodal region between the anti-nodes?

Keep in mind that the probabilistic distribution happens across preparing many instances of the state. It isn't a time average of one state. The particle doesn't move around and spend more time at more probable locations. It is more likely to be put somewhere when the state was prepared, and then only if there is a spatial phase gradient does it move in time after the state is made.

So if you have nodes at a certain radius it starts in one of the regions and then stays there. And this is fine since the probability of starting in each region was correct.

Comment: Wouldn't the particle move between the anti-nodes? And when it does so, wouldn't it have a chance of being found in the nodal region between the anti-nodes?

Comment: @Sidd Edited to respond

Comment: While this is an old post, I figure I'd comment just for other readers who may come across it. I think the reason such a poster would think the particles would move into the nodes is perhaps because he imagined that Bohmian mechanics - and it's intuitively appealing, but incorrect, to think - would somehow help to resurrect the notion of the old Bohr and Rutherford "planetary" models where the electrons are orbiting around and around, perhaps with more elaborate, non-Newtonian looking "orbits". This is wrong. In fact, the Bohmian atom in some sense resembles (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) more a cross between Rutherford's nuclear model and Thomson's even earlier "plum pudding" atom, where the electrons are "embedded" in fixed positions in a solid matrix of "pudding". The difference is that the "pudding" in the Thomson atom is imagined as carrying the positive charge, but in the Bohmian atom this is in the nucleus since we know a nucleus exists thanks to Rutherford's experiments, and instead the electrons are embedded in the surrounding space, kept there by the wave function.